# How to get CASE statement's value's substring?

Tags: sql

I have one scenario where i want to get substring of CASE statement.
For Ex:

```
CASE WHEN PT.PURCHID LIKE '[A-Z]%'
THEN LEFT(PT.PURCHID, CHARINDEX('-', PT.PURCHID) - 1) 
ELSE 'NA' 
END AS [A],
SUBSTRING([A],1,3) AS PURCHASE_ORDER_PREFIX
```

I want [A] to be substring.
Please help

Comment: Looks more like a case expression.

Comment: It depends on exact DBMS you're using. For example, in SQL Server strating from 2005 version you can `outer apply` your `case` expression to the query and use its value in any way you need.

Comment: Maybe give a sample `PURCHID` and what you expect as an output in the different cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can not perform substring on the alias [A], so simply use the CASE once more:

```
CASE WHEN PT.PURCHID LIKE '[A-Z]%'
THEN LEFT(PT.PURCHID, CHARINDEX('-', PT.PURCHID) - 1) 
ELSE 'NA' 
END AS [A],
SUBSTRING(CASE WHEN PT.PURCHID LIKE '[A-Z]%'
          THEN LEFT(PT.PURCHID, CHARINDEX('-', PT.PURCHID) - 1) 
          ELSE 'NA' 
          END,1,3) AS PURCHASE_ORDER_PREFIX
```

Answer (score 0):

The `SUBSTRING` is executed parallel with the `CASE WHEN` function (remember, SQL uses set operations, not procedural). This means `[A]` might not have been computed when the `SUBSTRING` wants to execute. This is why the SQL parser doesn't recognize `[A]` in that scope.

You have 2 options:

1) Replace the `[A]` in the `SUBSTRING` function with the exact same code that makes up `[A]`. This is not preferred, because it results in duplicate code.

2) Remove the `SUBSTRING` function from the current query, wrap the original query like this :

```
SELECT *
, SUBSTRING([A],1,3) AS PURCHASE_ORDER_PREFIX 
FROM ( /* ORIGINAL QUERY */) AS ResultSet
```